# Implementing an Iterative Process: Python

Tags: python, recursion

I find the smallest divisor of a number with this code:

```
def smallestDisvisor(n):
    return factor(n,2)

def factor(n,divisor):
    if (square(divisor) - n > 0):
        return n
    elif (n % divisor == 0):
        return divisor
    else:
        return factor(n,divisor + 1)

print(smallestDisvisor(32452843))
```

However, when I run this with a large enough value, I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

I do not understand the recursion error. Isn't this code implementing an iterative process?

```
factor(32452843,2) -> factor(32452843,3) -> factor(32452843,4)...
```

If not, how can I implement an iterative process for this algorithm?

Comment: You'd have to use a `while` loop instead of recursion

Comment: Python doesn't have tail-call optimisation ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13591970/660921)), so the recursion doesn't unwind like you describe. You need to use a loop.

Comment: Are you saying we cannot implement an iterative process in Python?

Comment: It's quite straightforward to implement an iterative process -- but that suggests that you use the iterative control structures: **for, while**, etc.

Comment: well...actually recursive process and recursive procedure call are different things: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254240/sicp-recursive-process-vs-iterative-process-using-a-recursive-procedure-to-gene

Comment: then I presume that you come from Haskel or some other functional language ??

Comment: well no...I just wanted to implement the iterative process using recursive calls...Is it not possible in Python?

Comment: Ah.  Got.  Yes, you can do that.

Comment: yes, you can as long as you use tail recursion optimization helper of some kind because [python don't have one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion). You can use this decorator for that [tail-call-optimization-decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474088-tail-call-optimization-decorator/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand the problem: implement an iterative process using recursion.

Yes, you can do this.  What tripped you up is the default stack recursion limit.  Since your recursion for a prime **N** takes **sqrt(N)** calls, you're limited to handling numbers <= MAX_STACK_RECURSION_DEPTH^2.

Your choices are to increase the depth from the default of 1000:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

or to use a more call-efficient algorithm, such as one that considers only prime divisors:

```
def smallestDisvisor(n):
    return factor(n, 2, [])

def factor(n, divisor, prime_list):
    # See whether any prime divides teh current divisor.
    #   Increment it until we get a new prime.
    while any(divisor % prime == 0 for prime in prime_list):
        divisor += 1 

    if (divisor * divisor > n):
        return n
    elif (n % divisor == 0):
        return divisor
    else:
        return factor(n, divisor + 1, prime_list + [divisor] )

print(smallestDisvisor(32452843))
```

---

**Answer to comment:**

A call adds a frame to the stack.  Regardless of the theoretical nature of the process, you cannot make a function call without adding a stack frame.  That's inherent in the run-time system.  If you want an iterative process to have only one stack frame, then you must write an iterative implementation.

Comment: But shouldn't an iterative process use just one stack frame.

Comment: @sarthak yes if its implementing as a iteration with the while/for loop construct, but here you are using a recursive call and python don't know how to optimize that even if you use a tail recursion form, so each call add a new stack frame for each function you call regardless of the function.

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated in the comments, Python does not have tail recursion optimization. You're seeing the error simply because the stack becomes too big to handle.

**EDIT**

Here is one way to get the smallest factor iteratively:

```
# if you're using python3, import reduce from functools
from functools import reduce

def get_factors(n):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    while i < n:
        if (n % i) == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            if reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, factors) >= n:
                return factors
        i = i + 1
    return factors
```

This will return a list of all of the factors. To get the smallest, you can look at the first element. since 32452843 is prime, the list will be empty.